# How to map-reduce sequental data, where Kn+1->Vn+1 = f(Kn->Vn)?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I got a more theoretical question, but it relates to conversion of the tasks I've been solving in my past without Hadoop to map-reduce platform.

For example, we have a video file, which is technically a sequence of frames, and we need to detect features of some round object in each frame: (x, y, size, distortion). The detection algorithm takes as input 2 things: frame itself and the results of recognition for the previous frame.

The question here is, how to convert such problem to map-reduce paradigm, so that:

1. benefits from having a reducer will be used, in my case I can imagine only mapper
2. algorithm will be able to work with the sequence, not only the each frame individually.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to keep the data from each frame, you will not need a
   Reduce step.  The Reduce step is optional in Hadoop.  If you want to
   run some statistic (e.g. average your data across all frames), a
   reducer can be used.
2. MapReduce does not lend itself well to sequential processing like
   this.

   1. If you have multiple videos to process, you could have each mapper
      process one video.  This will give you data parallelism.
   2. You can look at related Hadoop technologies like [Apache Hama](http://hama.apache.org/) or [HaLoop](http://code.google.com/p/haloop/) that are designed for sequential processing in parallel.

Comment: Although I appreciate the reference to the other techniques ;), I think you can simply express this with a mapper for each video, where a local variable keeps track of the last frames recognition result. I wouldn't personally use Hama/HaLoop for that, because this doesn't need communication between the tasks, nor strong iterative work.

Comment: I agree.  Without knowing the algorithm, I would guess that the time to process one frame is similar to the network latency of emitting a record for the next iteration.  Also, if you don't have a large number of videos, Hadoop is probably not necessary since you do not have a big data need.